# How to copy only new records from DynamoDB to S3 using Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a DynamoDB database with a lot of records, which increase every day. Recently I've exported all my records from DynamoDB to S3 bucket using Pipeline and it was OK. But now I want to create another Pipeline and export only new records from DynamoDB to this bucket. How can I make it?

Comment: Add another column to mark as exported or not, Then query on it? Or based on your existed columns to query? Just a throught!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switched to DynamoDB - Redshift option.